# reset button clears the input but deosn't re-render the component, how it works then?

Tags: reactjs

I am using React. In the code below, when I click on the Reset button, it clears the input and set the default value 'Dear .' back.
What is happening? why doesn't it reset the `Dear .` too? and after clicking on Reset button I assume that it re-renders, but `console.log('rende');` is not called! why?

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class SearchBar extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('cons');
    this.onInputchange = this.onInputchange.bind(this);
    this.state = { name: 'Dear. ' };
}

onInputchange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
}

render() {
    console.log('rende');
    return (
        <form className="input-group">
            <input
                className="form-control"
                value={this.state.name}
                onChange={this.onInputchange}
                placeholder="enter the name please "
            />
            <span className="input-group-btn">
                <button type="reset" className="btn btn-secondary">Reset</button>
            </span>
        </form>


     );
    }
}

export default connect()(SearchBar);
```

Answer (score 1):

your code should be like this. You're directly change DOM element without reactjs lifecycle & Virtual DOM concepts.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class SearchBar extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('cons');
    this.onInputchange = this.onInputchange.bind(this);
    this.onResetHandler = this.onResetHandler.bind(this);
    this.state = { name: 'Dear. ' };
}

onInputchange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
}

onResetHandler(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ name: 'Dear. '});
}

render() {
    console.log('rende');
    return (
        <form className="input-group">
            <input
                className="form-control"
                value={this.state.name}
                onChange={this.onInputchange}
                placeholder="enter the name please "
            />
            <span className="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={this.onResetHandler}>Reset</button>
            </span>
        </form>


     );
    }
}

export default connect()(SearchBar);
```

Comment: why should i do that when we have type="reset" ? so what is that for?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default event for the `button`, if it's inside a `form`.
In React, it's often to use `div` rather than `form` tag, since the default behavior for `form` is to jump to next page.

I'm using arrow function to simplify your code.

```
import React from 'react';

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  state = { name: 'Dear. ' };

onInputchange = event => {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
}

onResetClick = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.setState({ name: 'Dear. ' });
}

render() {
    return (
        <form className="input-group">
            <input
                className="form-control"
                value={this.state.name}
                onChange={this.onInputchange}
                placeholder="enter the name please "
            />
            <span className="input-group-btn">
                <button className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={this.onResetClick}>Reset</button>
            </span>
        </form>


     );
    }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

> The behavior of type='reset' is not to clear the form elements, but to return them to the initial/default values when the page was loaded.
>
> The reset button resets the form's inputs to their initial values, not
>   to blank. The reset button is used to clear all inputs by the user.

You have loaded input with `value={this.state.name}` so it have it's own value on load by default. So whenever you click reset, it's return to default value you passed. To actually clear the form, you will need to use **Events**.

For your understanding clear your `value={this.state.name}` to `defaultValue=""`

Now try to type in your input then click reset !!! you got it.

[check this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qtum5q)

read this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/reset)

Comment: to change it to the default mode it should re-render the component right?

Comment: no it won't, re-render happens only by changing props,state and setstate or forceUpdate, If you pass it through props or state it will re-render